# glossaries-extra symbols: setting the width of the name column and sorting mixed Greek/Latin entries

Tags: tables, nomenclature, glossaries-extra

1. How to fix the following to set the name column width to the widest entry name?
2. How to make the entries sorted in such a way that the Greek letters come first and are sorted before the Latin ones?
3. Is it possible to properly parse the Greek letter label when using it in both typesetting and sorting?

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{GlossaryEntries.bib}
    @symbol{vy,
        name = {\ensuremath{v_y}},
        description = {Lateral velocity}
    }
    @symbol{delta,
        name = {\ensuremath{\Delta}},
        description = {some symbol}
    }
    @symbol{α,
        name = {\ensuremath{\alpha}},
        description = {another symbol}
    }
    @symbol{F,
        name = {\ensuremath{F_{x,ij}^{D}}},
        description = {Dynamic longitudinal force of ij tire}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[
symbols, 
record,
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
match = {entrytype = symbol},
type = symbols,
selection = {all},
src = GlossaryEntries,
symbol-sort-fallback = {name},
break-at = {none},
]


\newlength\glsnamewidth

\newglossarystyle{nameunitdesc}{%
    \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth-\glsnamewidth-\tabcolsep}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{supertabular}{@{}p{\glsnamewidth}@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}}%
                p{\glsdescwidth}@{}}\toprule\addlinespace[5pt]}%
        {\bottomrule\end{supertabular}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \raggedright\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
        \glossentrydesc{##1}\tabularnewline
    }%
    \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{\glossentry{##2}{##3}}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \glsFindWidestAnyNameSymbol{\glsnamewidth}
    
    \gls{α} and \gls{delta}

    \printunsrtglossary[
    style = nameunitdesc,
    nonumberlist,
    type = symbols, 
    title = Nomenclature
    ]
    
\end{document}
```